# Which is more important : Texel or Pixel rate?

Tags: rendering, texture, pixels

I would like to know which is the most important ? More particularly in games or for the display of a desk (ex KDE Plasma, Windows 10 ...) ?

Comment: It’s been answered on stackoverflow already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224095/gpu-pixel-and-texel-write-speed

Comment: Since there's some really good answers on the SO question already, I'm going to close the question here to prevent information getting split up between the two sites. Please ignore the close reason in the banner!